# Can't Import seaborn

Tags: python, import, seaborn

I am trying to import seaborn in my Jupyter Notebook for drawing some plots, but somehow it gives me an error.
I am trying the following code to import seaborn:

```
!conda install -c anaconda seaborn --yes
import seaborn as sns
print('Seaborn installed and imported!')
```

but it gives me the following errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-e46449d32a66> in <module>
      5 # import library
      6 
----> 7 import seaborn as sns
      8 
      9 print('Seaborn installed and imported!')

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py in <module>
      7 from .utils import *
      8 from .palettes import *
----> 9 from .relational import *
     10 from .regression import *
     11 from .categorical import *

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/relational.py in <module>
     16 from .algorithms import bootstrap
     17 from .palettes import color_palette, cubehelix_palette, _parse_cubehelix_args
---> 18 from .axisgrid import FacetGrid, _facet_docs
     19 
     20 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/axisgrid.py in <module>
     14 from .palettes import color_palette, blend_palette
     15 from .external.six import string_types
---> 16 from .distributions import distplot, kdeplot,  _freedman_diaconis_bins
     17 
     18 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py in <module>
     14 
     15 try:
---> 16     import statsmodels.nonparametric.api as smnp
     17     _has_statsmodels = True
     18 except ImportError:

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/nonparametric/__init__.py in <module>
      5 """
      6 
----> 7 from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
      8 
      9 test = PytestTester()

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .tools import add_constant, categorical
      2 from statsmodels.tools._testing import PytestTester
      3 
      4 __all__ = ['test', 'add_constant', 'categorical']
      5 

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tools/tools.py in <module>
      3 '''
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nprf
      6 import numpy.linalg as L
      7 import pandas as pd

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py in <module>
     14 from numpy import ndarray, recarray
     15 from numpy.ma import MaskedArray
---> 16 from numpy.ma.mrecords import MaskedRecords
     17 from numpy.lib._iotools import _is_string_like
     18 from numpy.compat import basestring

~/conda/envs/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/ma/mrecords.py in <module>
     30 
     31 _byteorderconv = np.core.records._byteorderconv
---> 32 _typestr = ntypes._typestr
     33 
     34 import numpy.ma as ma

AttributeError: module 'numpy.core.numerictypes' has no attribute '_typestr'
```

I tried installing seaborn, upgrading seabonr, installing numpy, upgrading numpy, but nothing works so far.

Comment: https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/feature-selector/issues/24

Comment: How did you upgrade numpy?

Comment: !conda upgrade numpy --yes

Comment: Try this maybe? -> pip3 install numpy --upgrade